# Simple Javascript function not working in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML Code.

```
 <select onChange="TestCall()">
<option>Text1</option>
<option>Text2</option>
<option>Text3</option>
<option>Text4</option>
</select>
```

My JavaScript have a simple alert message like below.

```
 function TestCall()
{
 alert("Test");
}
```

Check the following Jsfiddle. I have added my script in the javascript area of jsfiddle. It is not working.

[**JSFIDDLE NOT WORKING HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9ukX/)

But If i move script block inside the HTML area of jsfiddle is working. Check the below one.

[**JSFIDDLE WORKING HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/W7JqS/)

What wrong in my code? Any Idea?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9ukX/2/ - On the 2nd dropdown under `Frameworks & Extensions`, choose No wrap in `<head>` or `<body>`

Comment: Don't apply listeners like this. It is annoying and not maintainable. `element.addEventListener('change', TestCall, false);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default JSFiddle wraps the JS block into `onLoad` function:

[image]

... leading to something like:

```
window.onload = function() {
    function TestCall() {
        alert("Test");
    }
};
```

This means that your `TestCall` method is getting out of global scope and is not accessible from HTML attributes.

Change the option to `No wrap - in <head>` or `No wrap - in <body>` and it will work.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q9ukX/3/

Comment: Thanks VisioN. But why it is not working in "onDomready" selection also?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Same reason: the code gets wrapped in `onDomReady` function and is getting out of global scope.

Answer (score 2):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9ukX/1/)**

It works if you change the settings down the side.

Change it from `onLoad` to `No Wrap - in body` or `No Wrap - in head`.