# Javascripts calculates total based on form selections

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an html form that I want to use javascript to calculate the total based on values of the form selection.

I was able to get my code work, but after trying to save it to JS fiddle it doesn't seem to be calculating anymore. Is there something in my code that is causing the error?

Here is the link to my full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/kmurray13/gc02Lsmh/

Here is just my javascript:

```
function calculatePrice(){

  //Get selected data  
  var elt = document.getElementById("Quantity");
  var quantity = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("size");
  var size = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("page_count");
  var page_count = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("cover_stock");
  var cover_stock = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  var elt = document.getElementById("text_stock");
  var text_stock = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

  //convert data to integers or decimals
  quantity = parseInt(quantity);
  size = parseFloat(size);
  page_count = parseInt(page_count);
  cover_stock = parseFloat(cover_stock);
  text_stock = parseFloat(text_stock);

 //calculate total value 
 var total = ((cover_stock * quantity)) + ((text_stock * page_count) * quantity); 

  //print value to  PicExtPrice 
  document.getElementById("PicExtPrice").value=total;

}
```

My goal is to get the calculation when you click the 'Calculate Price' button, but I am not sure what I have done to the code to cause this error.

Comment: `causing the error` - what error? Oh ... in jsfiddle, the javascript is, by default in a onload block ... simply change to "bottom of body" - https://jsfiddle.net/2ujw1xqL/

Comment: in jsfiddle, the javascript is, by default in a onload block ... simply change to "head"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Javascript function not working in jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993308/simple-javascript-function-not-working-in-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not anything in your code that's causing the issue. It's because you were loading the javascript in the onload event thus the calculatePrice function wasn't present in the DOM thus you were getting the error. Fixed here: https://jsfiddle.net/fm3g64x0/

[image]

Comment: Exactly my problem. Thank you so much. I am new to javascript and JS fiddle so clearly a rookie mistake. haha

Answer (score 0):

This is because jsFiddle is configured by default to wrap your JS code in onload event handler. If you look in your console you are getting a ReferenceError for `calculatePrice()` because it is out of scope.

In the Javascript jsFiddle pane, click where it says *JavaScript + No-Library (pure JS)* and where it says *Load Type* select *No wrap - bottom of*  and rerun your code.